# Hibernate Duplicate ID using TableGenerator in Oracle, MS SQL and H2

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, jta

I am experiencing a weird behavior where part of a long transaction I get duplicate ids.

I am using Jboss 7.2.0 and Hibernate 4.0.1.Final.

I have tried/experimented many solutions in vain: flush() after persist() and surrounding the insert with an embedded transaction (new).

Regards.

```
@TableGenerator(
table = "SEQUENCE_TABLE", name = "seq1", pkColumnName = "seq_name",
valueColumnName = "seq_val", pkColumnValue = "seq1", allocationSize = 1,
initialValue = 1001)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "seq1")
public Long getId() {
return super.getId();
}
```

in the base class (which sole purpose is to define common attributes such as the id, version, row modification timestamp ... etc) :

```
public Long id;

@Transient
public Long getId() {
 return id;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the `getId()` method in the base class and also the declaration for the `id` field?

Comment: the id is declared as 'public Long id' and the 'super.getId()' is '@Transient public Long getId() {return id;}'

Comment: Please add that to the question text, I can't see your code in the previous comment.